# Laravel Controller another function is being called

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.3

I'm getting

> ErrorException in ProjectController.php line 41: Trying to get
>   property of non-object

I am calling **delete_project()** inside my controller but it seems Laravel is also calling the **get_project($variable_here)** method

*ProjectsController*

```
public function get_project($slug_name){
    $project = Project::where('slug_name', $slug_name)->first();
    if ($project->user_id == Auth::user()->id) {
      return view('project', ['project' => $project]);
    }else {
      return redirect('console');
    }
}

public function delete_project(){

}
```

*Web routes*

```
Route::get('/console', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('project/{slug_name}', 'ProjectController@get_project');

Route::get('get_projects', 'UserController@get_projects');

Route::post('create_new_project', 'ProjectController@create_new_project');

Route::post('/delete_project', 'ProjectController@delete_project');
```

Comment: Please show `get_project` route.

Comment: Oops sorry I forgot that line.

Route::get('get_projects', 'UserController@get_projects');

Comment: Routes look fine. Try to clear route cache with `php artisan route:clear` command.

Comment: Still same result bro.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding this **input** on my form to send a **delete request**

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
```

And changing the delete_project route so I now have this on my web routes

```
Route::get('/project/{slug_name}', 'ProjectController@get_project');
Route::delete('/project/{slug_name}', 'ProjectController@delete_project');
```